# Merging values in different columns into one in python list

Tags: python, list, pandas, merge

I have a list like the one below.

```
Gamecode    rush    pass
23....89     347    
23....89             650
23....90     654    
23....90             230
```

the code is below.

```
temp = {}
for row in combineddff.itertuples():
    temp={}
    if row[1] in ('RUSH', 'PASS'):
        temp['GameCode'] =  row[0]
        if row[1] == 'RUSH':
            temp['rush'] = row[10]
        else:
             temp['pass'] = row[10]

    else:
        continue
    templist.append(temp)

print templist
my_df = pd.DataFrame(templist)
my_df.to_csv('data/results_yards.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

I want to combine the rush and pass values of separate rows in the templist into one row with "GameCode", "Rush" and "Pass" as values. kindly help.

Comment: Provide information in the question. Not in links and definitely not using images.

Comment: I understand. I'm sorry. Should I use this post now, or create a new one ?

Comment: Edit this post. And provide all information that is needed to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example. Better yet - create one yourself and share it so people are motivated to help you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your columns are 'None' if there is no value.

```
game_code = 'GameCode'
pass_yds = 'PASS'
rush_yds = 'RUSH'

output_list = []
for row in combineddff.itertuples():
    if row[0] == game_code:
        if row[2] is not None: pass_yds = row[2]
        if row[1] is not None: rush_yds = row[1]
    else:
        output = (game_code, pass_yds, rush_yds)
        output_list.append(output)

# Flush the last group
output = (game_code, pass_yds, rush_yds)
output_list.append(output)
```

**Edit: after comments**

```
templist = [
    { 'GameCode': 'A', 'PASS': '1' },
    { 'GameCode': 'A', 'RUN': '2' },
    { 'GameCode': 'B', 'PASS': '3' },
    { 'GameCode': 'B', 'RUN': '4' },
]

merged = None
output_list = []

for t in templist:
    if merged is None:
        merged = t
    elif merged['GameCode'] == t['GameCode']:
        merged.update(t)
    else:
        output_list.append(merged)
        merged = t
```

Comment: This is what I've been looking for. Only that instead of using combineddff.itertuples(), I want to use templist from my original post.
Here, I'm getting keyerror @ if row[0] == game_code:,  if i use templist instead of combineddff.itertuples()

Comment: Does your `templist` contain tuples, lists, or dicts? If it's dicts, you might have to use `row['GameCode']` or something.

Comment: Yes, each value inside the list is a dict with either (gamecode,pass) or (gamecode,rush) with gamecode and rush are being the key values in dicts.  So in your code in the line "if row['GameCode'] == game_code:" Is it checking the string "GameCode" or its key value ?

Comment: I have added a different piece of code, based on what I think your templist looks like. Is that more accurate?

Answer (score 1):

try to use pd.merge method:

```
import pandas as pd

rush = pd.DataFrame({'Gamecode': [2389, 2390], 'rush': [347, 654]})
pss = pd.DataFrame({'Gamecode': [2389, 2390], 'pass': [650, 230]})

print(pd.merge(rush, pss, on='Gamecode'))
```

Output:

```
   Gamecode  rush  pass
0      2389   347   650
1      2390   654   230
```

Comment: They don't belong to separate data frames. Templist is a list and they belong to separate rows, as in rush value is present in one row and pass value is present in another(As you can see in the example list I have provided). It may be because of my code above. 

Or do you want me to get them both separately and do the merge ?

Comment: it would be easier to help you if you would provide a few rows, representing "combineddff" dataframe. but not having this information and following your logic i presume it would be easier to have two different dataframes and merge them.

Comment: I understand. I should have done that. Now it is not allowing me to add a head of my data frame here. Is there any way I can add it here ? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @GowrisankarGopalakrishnan, you can publish your **text** file with the dataframe (input data) in the internet, so another users with higher reputation can add it to your question